# Not working locale on route as parameter

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.1

I have a problem with my route, when try to access homepage, I get the error:

> "No route found for "GET /"

My config file (app/config/config.yml):

```
parameters:
locale: en

framework:
#esi: ~
translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
router:
    resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
    strict_requirements: ~
default_locale: '%locale%'
```

My route file (app/config/routing.yml)

```
web_client:
resource: "@DesktopBundle/Resources/config/routing_web.yml"
prefix: /{_locale}
defaults: { _locale: en}
requirements:
    _locale: en|fr
```

My route second file (src/Resources/config/routing_web.yml)

```
home_page:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: DesktopBundle:Website/HomePage:homePage}
```

My action:

```
public function homePageAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('DesktopBundle:Web:layout.html.twig', array());
}
```

When I try to access base url I have a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will have a 404 error, AFAIU you prefix your route with *_locale* and then reading your resource file with *home_page* data, so the route will be something like this:

*example.com/en/* <- then you will get your homepage, because it matches your prefix (/{_locale}/) and path for homepage(/)

To get your homePageAction after entering example.com, you need to move the route for homepage in routing.yml, above the web_client one.

**EDIT:**
To redirect read this [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html)
You need something like this:

```
home_page:
    pattern: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /en
        permanent: true

web_client:
    resource: "@DesktopBundle/Resources/config/routing_web.yml"
    prefix: /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: en}
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the idea...I want default locale to be 'en', If I will wrote example.com the redirect to example.com/en

Comment: If I want to add a new route for example : /contact...I need to create in both : routing.yml & routing_web.yml ?

Comment: For example.com/en/contact and example.com/fr/contact you need to add /contact only in routing_web.yml, cause this file works only for routes that starts with /{_locale}/ (as you specified in _webclient_ section), so one without locale will lead to 404 error